# Unable to connect to SQL Server on domain

Tags: sql-server, virtualbox

I have been trying to connect to the SQL server in my domain for several days. I have a virtual box network with a client and a server. Only the client can’t find the sql server on my server. I followed all the steps to allow my database to comminuqer on port 1433 but nothing changes.

I don’t know what to do, I enabled TCP/IP with port 1433 and allowed connections in my database, as everyone recommends.

I have no server proposal and when I test with ip, I also have a mistake :

[image: client]

I added a new rule on my server:

[image: new_rule]

The answer may be simple for some but I am not an expert in software development, I hope some will have answers.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Sounds more like an issue with virtualbox configuration than anything to do with C#/.NET/VisualStudio

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is there a way to verify that this comes from the configuration of virtual box ?

Comment: How are you configuring the network ports in VB? Are you using NAT  or Bridged or one of the other methods?

Comment: The client and the server are in internal network, I have a router that has a NAT adapter and the second adapter in internal network

Comment: Are you sure SQL Server is running? Are you sure it runs on port 1433 (which it won't if it's a named instance, like `\SQLEXPRESS`)? Have you tried completely disabling firewall (on every OS involved and any settings in VirtualBox)? Have you tested with [`Test-NetConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection)? Do `ping`/`tracert` get there?

Comment: (Also, FWIW, long ago I grew very tired of all the extra config a VM requires, and all the layers it puts between you and the database you're connecting to. You should consider a docker container running a SQL Server image, then it's just `<host IP>,<port>` and no operating system stuff in between.)

Comment: On the target server have you checked in SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration yet? There will be a subitem for each installed instance, and each of those will list configurations for Named Pipes, Shared Memory and TCP/IP. Is the TCP/IP protocol enabled? Inside the properties of TCP/IP what listening addresses are enabled and which ports are they listening on?

Comment: Inside the VB guest you can use PowerShell's [`Test-NetConnection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/test-netconnection) to confirm that the target server and port are accessible. Or if that's not available even `telnet`. Your SQL tools won't be able to connect unless either of those tools can connect to the port on which that server is listening.